# Issues in spring-integration-kafka consumer which can't receive message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I started using `spring-integration-kafka` in my project, and I can produce message, but consumer can't receive message ,I don't know why .

This is my code,

the kafka-producer-context.xml

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka"/>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutbundChannelAdaptor"
                                    kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProductorContext"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    order="1">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="producerProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">3600000</prop>
            <prop key="queue.buffering.max.ms">500</prop>
            <prop key="queue.buffering.max.messages">10000</prop>
            <prop key="retry.backoff.ms">100</prop>
            <prop key="message.send.max.retries">2</prop>
            <prop key="socket.request.max.bytes" >104857600</prop>
            <prop key="send.buffer.bytes" >5242880</prop>
            <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes" >1048576</prop>
            <prop key="socket.send.buffer.bytes" >1048576</prop>
            <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProductorContext"
    producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration
            broker-list="localhost:9092" 
            key-class-type="java.lang.String"
            value-class-type="java.lang.String"
            topic="test"
            async="true"
            partitioner="partitioner" 
            key-encoder="encoder"
            value-encoder="encoder"
            compression-codec="default"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>

<bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.DefaultPartitioner"/>

<bean id="encoder"
class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder" />

<!-- <bean id="kafkaEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
</bean> -->
```

**producer**

```
public class Productor {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("inputToKafka")
private MessageChannel chanel;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(Productor.class);

public void sendMessage(String message) {

    try {
        boolean flag = chanel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message)
                .setHeader("topic", "test").setHeader("messageKey", "key")
                .build());
        System.out.println(flag);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(String.format("Failed to send [ %s ] to topic %s ",
                message, "test"), e);

    }

}
```

**the kafka-consumer-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.rminfo"/>

<int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="kafkaMessageExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="kafkaMessageExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />

<!-- channel配置 auto-startup="true"  否则接收不发数据 -->
<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter"
    kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext" auto-startup="true" 
    channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
            max-messages-per-poll="5" />
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inputFromKafka" ref="kafkaConsumer" method="processMessage" /> -->
<!-- <bean id="kafkaConsumer" class="net.rminfo.demo.Customer"/> -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="inputFromKafka" ref="kafkaConsumer" method="processMessage" />


<bean id="consumerProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="auto.offset.reset">smallest</prop>
            <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">10485760</prop> <!-- 10M -->
            <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">5242880</prop>
            <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">1000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- zookeeper配置 可以配置多个 -->
<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="localhost:2181" zk-connection-timeout="4000"
    zk-session-timeout="4000" zk-sync-time="200"/>

<int-kafka:consumer-context 
    id="consumerContext" consumer-timeout="1000"
    zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect" consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="mygroup" max-messages="5000" >
            <int-kafka:topic streams="3" id="test"/>
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>
```

**consumer**

```
@Component("kafkaConsumer")
public class Customer {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Customer.class);

@ServiceActivator
public void processMessage(Map<String, Map<Integer, List<byte[]>>> msgs) {
    logger.info("===============processMessage===============");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, List<byte[]>>> entry : msgs
            .entrySet()) {
        logger.info("============Topic:" + entry.getKey());
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<byte[]>> messages = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<byte[]>>) entry
                .getValue();
        Set<Integer> keys = messages.keySet();
        for (Integer i : keys)
            logger.info("======Partition:" + i);
        Collection<List<byte[]>> values = messages.values();
        for (Iterator<List<byte[]>> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            List<byte[]> list = iterator.next();
            for (byte[] object : list) {
                String message = new String(object);
                logger.info("=====message:" + message);
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just started using Kafka, it would be better to switch to the latest Spring Integration Kafka version which is based already on the Apache Kafka 0.9.

Everything what you show here is deprecated.

See the recent RC release blog post: https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/07/spring-integration-kafka-support-2-0-0-release-candidate-is-now-available

Answer (score 0):

Please change **max-messages="5000"** in your **kafka-consumer-context.xml** to **max-messages="1"** and see if it works.